# Enable spread operator using babel/preset-env in node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I'm using node version **14**

Here's my **package.json** file:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./src/app.js",
        "build": "babel ./src -s -d dist",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
        "@babel/node": "^7.10.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
    }
}
```

and here's **babel.config.json** file:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Now I guess that `"@babel/preset-env"` allows us to use the latest JavaScript.
When I run `npm start` everything works OK.
But if i `run npm run build` i got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: src/api/review/controller.js: Unexpected token (8:25)
   6 | 
   7 | module.exports.create = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
>  8 |     const reviewData = { ...req.body, user: req.user._id };
     |                          ^
   9 |     const review = await Review.create(reviewData);
  10 |     response.build(res, review, 201);
  11 | });
```

I added a new plugin to make it work `"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.10.4"`

and here's **babel.config.json** file:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

But I didn't work

Comment: you need [babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/), and add on configuration file `{"plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]}`

Comment: @RapSherlock already tried that. didn't work.

Comment: @RapSherlock 7.10.3

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by adding the following package: `"@babel/cli": "^7.10.4"`

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
```

then change your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Comment: `.babelrc` ? Did you changed ?

Comment: I have babel.config.json and yes i changed it